# Eclipse Clearcase plugin: Error making file(s) writable

Tags: eclipse, version-control, clearcase

I'm trying to use Rational SCM Adapter 7.5 on Eclipse 3.5 on a Linux machine.

The plugin installation was successful and the clearcase menus all appear correctly. 
But, I'm unable to checkout the file via Package Explorer -> Team -> Checkout. The checkout dialog does not appear.

When I try to edit the file in the editor pane, the Checkout dialog appears. But, when I try to checkout the file, I get the following error:

```
!ENTRY com.rational.clearcase.linux 4 0 2011-04-15 03:35:38.469
!MESSAGE CCFileModificationValidator::validateEdit: Error making file(s) writeable
User canceled checkout or checkout failed:
```

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a current bug, only fixed in [Rational Application Developer for WebSphere Software 7.5.3](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21418774), but not back-ported yet in the [Rational SCM adapter 7.5.0](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24025674).

(Even though the p2 update site http://www3.software.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/rationalsdp/clearcase/60/update/windows/ shows a `com.rational.clearcase_7.5.0.v201102110950.jar` quite recent)

Comment: I'm getting the same error even with Rational SCM Adapter 7.0

Comment: @donzerus: so that means it isn't a "blocked handle on some resource" issue, but a bug within the plugin itself.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that if you use the checkout button in the toolbar instead of using the Team menu, this error doesn't occur.